# Acumatica Tree View - Node Selected Event?

Tags: acumatica

I'm building a standalone PXTreeView which contains a list of nodes and when each node is clicked the idea is to trigger a method or action in the graph.

My problem is I'm not sure if this is supported, the Tree View supports the Master/Detail concept fine but my idea is much simpler, all I need is a call back event to trigger in my graph whenever a node is selected.

I have tried using this event:

protected void _(Events.FieldSelecting<TreeViewNode, TreeViewNode.nodeID> e)

This will trigger when a node is selected, however it triggers for ALL nodes in the tree regardless of the selected node, so I have no idea which node was actually selected by the user.

What I'm looking for is something similar to a button Link Command where I can implement a custom action to execute based on the selected node (the custom action will navigate to a dynamic URL).

Another possibility is to leverage the PXTreeItemBinding field named NavigateURLField, but no matter what I populate this with it's ignored when a node is selected.

Have read this article but the purpose of this example is slightly different i.e. Master/Detail vs Standalone
https://www.acumatica.com/blog/a-tree-with-a-view/

Here is my graph:

`public class TreeViewTest : PXGraph
{
public PXSelect Nodes;
public PXSelect<TreeViewNode, Where<TreeViewNode.nodeID, Equal<Current<TreeViewNode.nodeID>>>> SelectedNode;

```
protected void _(Events.FieldSelecting<TreeViewNode, TreeViewNode.nodeID> e)
{
    if (e.Row == null)
        return;

    var x = e.Row;
}

protected virtual IEnumerable nodes([PXDBGuid] Guid? nodeID)
{
    if (nodeID == null)
    {
        var root = new TreeViewNode
        {
            NodeID = new Guid("00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"),
            NodeName = "Root"
        };
        yield return root;
    }
    else
    {

        PXResultset<TreeViewNode> nodesForParent = PXSelect<TreeViewNode, Where<TreeViewNode.parentID, Equal<Required<TreeViewNode.parentID>>>>.Select(this, nodeID);

        foreach (var item in nodesForParent)
        {
            TreeViewNode node = item;
            yield return node;
        }
    }
}
```

}`

Any ideas appreciated, thank you.

Comment: do you have IsKey on your TreeViewNode? Field Selecting will run for all rows. It is normally used for unbound field calculations. On the views it looks like other examples are using "Argument" in place of "Current". (Comparing to VisualBOMMaint graph)

Comment: Hi @Brendan, thanks for your input, yes I had IsKey set in the Node DAC. Have since figured out a workaround - basically once I implemented the 'Template2' tree view control (previously I left it empty) and bound the Form DataMember to the SelectedNode view (as per my code example) I can then override the view binding, so now whenever a user selects a new Node the overridden view method is triggered once for the newly selected node. Not the best solution but seems to achieve what I'm looking for.